# HTTP Authentication failing in AJAX for postmates api

Tags: javascript, ajax, postmates

I'm trying to use the **postmates API**, which first requires us to authenticate ourselves using http basic authentication.  The `username` field in the code below is where we inserted our `private API key`.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Request with custom header
        $.ajax({
            url: ' http://username:@api.postmates.com',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(response) { alert("Success"); },
            error: function(error) {alert(error); }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The error we are getting is

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.postmates.com/?callback=jQuery112008309037607698633_1462052396724&_=1462052396725.
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Answer (score 0):

need the authentication

https://postmates.com/developer/docs#authentication

> The actual header that is used will be a base64-encoded string like
>   this:
>
> Basic Y2YyZjJkNmQtYTMxNC00NGE4LWI2MDAtNTA1M2MwYWYzMTY1Og==

Try to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Request with custom header
        $.ajax({
            url: ' http://username:@api.postmates.com',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(response) { alert("Success"); },
            error: function(error) {alert(error); },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic Y2YyZjJkNmQtYTMxNC00NGE4LWI2MDAtNTA1M2MwYWYzMTY1Og==");
                    }
        });
    });
```

I don't test because jsfiddle block external petitions.